# wkhtmltopdf vertical-align baseline ignored

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I have the following html markup, where I want to use different font and fontsize for the first letter:

```
<table class="maintable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class='first-letter'>E</span>s war einmal ein Prinz, der auf der Suche nach der richtigen Frau war.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I use the following CSS

```
body {
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    font-size: 3.5mm;
    line-height: 6.0mm;
}
.first-letter {
    font-family: 'arabesqueinitialen', Arial;
    font-size: 15mm;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.maintable td {
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

If I run this in Chrome I get the following result:

[image]

which is exactly what I want.

But when I convert this with wkhtmltopdf I get this:

[image]

As you can see, the vertical alignment of the first letter is wrong.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have the problem, but I had this same problem, the reason I found was that the element affected (image, table, chart, etc) was close to the page break, I think that with a `<br>` before your line would be enought.

Another way is specify where do you want your page break in the css file, like this

```
p{
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}
.pagebreak {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

That way you won't have pagebreak inside paragraphs and can specify where do you want the page break with the class pagebreak.

If you still have problems with the vertical align, you can search in the WkHtmltoPdf GitHub page [GitHub WkHtmlToPdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues)